# How do I prevent Microsoft Word from pasting a picture as a bullet?

Tags: images, copy-paste, microsoft-word-2013, bullets

I'm trying to make a printable list of keyboard shortcuts using images to take the place of the Win key, Ctrl key, etc.  The problem is, every time I paste one of these images at the start of a line, it converts my image to a bullet (of the image) and makes the line part of a bulleted list.  I don't have any lists in my document and I just want the image to appear inline with the text.

I found some clunky workarounds such as including extra characters in the copy or doing a right-click then selecting "paste image".  But I cannot just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> and have it work right.  I have been through all the options I can find for Word 2013 (e.g., Smart Paste, preserve list formatting, etc.) and none seem to disable this behavior.